# How to evaluate this partial derivative on multivariate polynomial?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

This is a polynomial that I found in my research, and I'd like to know a *simplified* form.

---

I have a very simple degree-$n$ multivariate polynomial $p(x,z_1,\cdots,z_n) = (x + z_1 + \cdots +z_n)^n$.

I'd like to apply a set of *simple* operations to convert $p(x,z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ into a univariate polynomial $q(x)$.

\begin{equation*}
q(x) =
\left[
\left(
\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1 - \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}\right)
\right)
p(x,z_1,\cdots,z_n)
\right]
\Bigg|_{z_1=\cdots=z_n=0}.
\end{equation*}

One can easily see that the conversion is composed of two kinds of operations:

- Restriction: Setting a certain variable $z_i = 0$ in a multivariate polynomial; that is, $r(x,z_1,\cdots,z_{n-1},z_n)|_{z_n=0} = r(x,z_1,\cdots,z_{n-1},0)$.
- Differentiation: $(1 - \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i})r(x,z_1,\cdots,z_n) = r(x,z_1,\cdots,z_n) - \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}r(x,z_1,\cdots,z_n)$.

---

I'd like to know how $q(x)$ looks for any $n$. Is there any closed form for this univariate polynomial $q(x)$? Can I actually expand the definition of $q(x)$ and find a simplified form?

Comment: First rewrite the differential operator. Notice that it is equal to $I-\sigma_1+\sigma_2-...+(-1)^n\sigma_n$, where $\sigma_i$ is the elementary symmetric function of degree $i$, in the $n$ differentiations $\partial/\partial z_k$. Then you compute what is is $\sigma_i$ applied to $p$ (and restricted to $z_1=...=z_n=0$).

Comment: Observe that computing $\sigma_i$ applied to $p$ is not difficult. $\sigma_i p=\binom{n}{i}\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}(x+z_1+...+z_n)^{n-i}$. Therefore, putting the $z$'s equal to zero, we get: $\binom{n}{i}\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}x^{n-i}$

Comment: We can put this in the formula for $q$ to get $q=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}x^{n-i}$.